# Send form through ajax with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using ajax to submit a form. The form consist two tables and multiple input. The form id is `frmCreateRate`. Both `dataTable1` and `dataTable2` working fine. I want to submit `frmCreateRate` along with `dataTable1` and `dataTable2`. I try to use this code but it shows null value. Here is the code :

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: "/Rate/CreateRate",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data:  JSON.stringify({Observations:dataTable2, Summary: dataTable1, Input: $('#frmCreateRate').serialize()}),
        dataType: "json",            
    });
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateRate(List<Observations> Observations, List<Summaries> Summary, StaffDomain Input)
{
    //Codes
}
```

I try working with only `dataTable1` and `dataTable2`, he value from both tables are captured at the controller. But when I add another parameter which is `frmCreateRate`, it shows null value.

Update:

Here is some code inside the controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateRate(List<Observations> Observations, List<Summaries> Summary, StaffDomain Input)
   {
        var domain = new StaffRecord
        {
            Diagnosis = Input.Diagnosis,
            Code = Input.Code,
            Time = Input.Time,
            Date = Input.Date,
            Department = Input.Department,
            STaffInformed = Input.STaffInformed,
            TimeArrived = Input.TimeArrived,

        };

        db.StaffRecords.Add(domain);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `serialize()` function is used to submit the form as standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME, which looks something like this:

```
single=MySingleValue&check=checkboxValue&radio=radioValue
```

You are sending `application/json` MIME, so you'll have to add the form values by yourself one by one to the JSON object just like you did with `dataTable2` and `dataTable1`. It is strongly recommended not to send a complex object in one parameter. However, it you wish to ignore the recommendation and continue with your current design, you can automate the serialization of the form instead of adding the values one by one. To do so, you can use the `serializeArray()` function along with a helper method.

The `serializeArray()` serializes the form elements as an array of names and values, like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "textbox1",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "textbox2",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "textbox3",
    value: "3"
  }
]
```

To convert it to a JSON object, you can use this helper method:

```
function serializeFormToJson(selector) {
  var formArray = $(selector).serializeArray();
  var json = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++) {
    json[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
  }
  return json;
}
```

Now you can change your Ajax call to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: "/Rate/CreateRate",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({Observations: dataTable2, Summary: dataTable1, Input: serializeFormToJson("#frmCreateRate")}),
    dataType: "json",            
});
```

Comment: The form has more than 10 inputs in it. Thats why I want to send it as a form so all the inputs value can be sent in one shot. I also try removing the `JSON.stringify` but the value in datatables are not captured in the controller

Comment: Yes, but then how are you processing those 10 different values? Post the relevant code in the `CreateRate` action for processing the `Input` parameter. Generally, it is not recommended to send a bunch of variables and values in one parameter like that, unless they're related (e.g. an array of values coming from a group of checkboxes). As for the datatables, it seems to be the same problem, sending a complex object in one parameter. You can post the code in the `CreateRate` action for processing the datatables if you like us to help you optimizing them too.

Comment: Ive updated my question. I actually send it as a form

Comment: Yes, like I said, it is strongly recommended not to send such a complex object in one parameter. However, see my updated answer for a solution. I don't see how you're using the datatables in your action and how you're building them in JavaScript, so I cannot recommend you on how to optimize them, so I kept the `JSON.stringify()` function.